# windows authentication with username and password in sql server filestream

Tags: sql-server, security, connection-string, windows-authentication, filestream

I am developing a sql server based database and I have to use FILESTREAM to stroe some large files. for using streaming api to upload/download/update filestream files from remote clients, i have to use windows authentication. 
but the problem is when using windows authentication, the remote user (that is registered as windows login in management studio) can retrieve connection string easily (because there is not any user/pass in it) and connect to database.
how can i use windows authentication and for example set a password that the user can only use my application exe file to connect to database?

```
connectionString="data source=SERVER\INSTANCE;
   Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True;"
```

I mean at the connection string above if the user know the database name, he can connect to database with a simple c# code rather than the my application and maybe have access levels more than desired to have.

Comment: If you have more to add to your question, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56871045/edit) your question.